# Is it possible to count code execution steps?

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

Is it prossible to report how many calculations where executed by a section of code?

I know the benchmark gem will report on runtime, but don't believe it'll count the number of calculations done.

Just to be clear, I'm talking about at the processor level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it appears it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

About memory usage, if you define the macro `CALC_EXACT_MALLOC_SIZE` (not sure where, but in `ruby.h` may work) and recompile Ruby, you will be able to call `GC.malloc_allocated_size` to know how much memory is allocated by malloc (almost everything), in bytes.

Comment: +1 @LBg: It was my fault for including the reference to memory, the question is really about calculation reporting. If I post another question related to Ruby memory reporting and link to it would you be willing to move your answer to it. If so I'll do that, and remove the reference to memory in this question. Thanks!